# Use a model inside GPU across Flask requests without initiating the model each time

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, huggingface-transformers

Each time I load a transformer model into GPU it takes ~60 seconds.

So, I want to access the model in GPU across flask requests without initiating it each time.

So, I tried to save the model in `BaseManager` and then access it.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

manager = BaseManager(('', 37844), b'password')
manager.connect()

generator = pipeline('text-generation', model=MODEL_NAME, device=1)
manager.register('generator', generator)
```

but while trying to access the model
with
`generator = manager.generator()`

I get the following error

`Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method`

and while digging further into the error it asked to use `multiprocessor` from `torch` instead but that doesn't have a `BaseManager`.

```
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Process, set_start_method
```

So, how does one efficiently use Models across requests in Flask?